# While I do file.read(1) is there a way to go back 1 byte?

Tags: python, file

I have to read 1 file letter by letter but sometimes I have to go a back byte (to read something that I have already read).

Is there anyway to make that happen?

Or how can I see the next byte without forwarding the file to then next position?

Comment: Unless your file is humongously big, and unless you're actually required to _read_ 1 byte each time (might be slow?), I would recommend reading everything in then iterating through that...

Comment: The thing is i have to read 1 byte at the time so what you mean is to read the whole file like content=file.read() and then start getting every byte?

Comment: text files or binary files? why do you need 1-byte pieces of it?  _"letter  by letter"_ sounds like texts - textfiles often are utf-8  which are not 1-byte-constant-lsized-etters ... one letter can be bigger then 1 byte

Comment: text i need to see every letter of the file but some times i have to go back or to be able to see what letter is ahead without having to move my current position the file forward

Comment: why on the file? Read the whole file as string and operate the string?

Comment: i just found a solution using file.seek(file.tell()-1) so it goes back if i need it to go thank you all for your help and time.

Comment: Wouldn't that be... incredibly slow in the long run?

Comment: Yes it is but for now i try to make it work like that and then i will try to optimize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will challenge your belief that you actually need to do that.

```
with open("babar.txt", 'rb') as file:
    text = file.read()
print(text[42])
```

then, what is the actual way to accomplish this:

```
with open("babar.txt", 'rb') as file:
    file.seek(42)
    print(file.read(1))
```

The first loads everything in RAM, and (if your file fits on RAM) it is incredibly fast. The second way is incredibly slow.

To go back one byte, you can do this:

```
with open("babar.txt", 'rb') as file:
    file.seek(42)
    print(file.read(1))
    file.seek(-1, 1) # goes back by one relative to current position
    print(file.read(1)) # reeds the same char
    file.seek(-1, 2) # goes at the end of the file
    print(file.read(1)) # reads the last char
```

Check the `whence` argument of `seek()`.

Generally, one can assume making a RAM access is 1000x faster than making a HDD access, so this is probably 1000x slower than the first option.

Comment: i tried seek(-1,1) i get this error 
can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks

Comment: You have to be in `byte` mode to be able to do that, add a `b` to your mode.

Comment: I know its faster i will try to make it having the whole file read in once but for now i will leave it like that.
What do you mean 1 byte mode?

Comment: `open("babar.txt", 'rb')`, when you read, it will give you a byte. Which is what you asked in the question.

Comment: o yea my bad sorry i didn't notice that you re right thank you

Answer (score -1):

i just found a solution using file.seek(file.tell()-1) so it goes back if i need it to go thank you all for your help and time.

Comment: That's the wrong way of doing it use `file.seek(-1, 1)` instead

Comment: already tried it i get this error
can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks